# User always redirects to login page with IE

Tags: asp.net, url, authentication

Already tried and tested several solutions but still could not solve the problem that occurs when using IE 11: on the basis of development works fine but when I publish to the production base, the user is always redirected to the login page.

Furthermore, IE 11 (and only IE 11), the URLs are not appearing as they should.

Example: in IE 11 I have 
`192.168.1.97:8080/(F(l3y4LnbO9OFvu_KMr9K_0usZD1lu_ykH8oyOBMmP6cf8sgf6hsHr7sQCWMkqF9SFVd_27MxCwLoFVsKGZ3YMMRJW4GiX8S4CbGsvmvz6bW7qOwNVZBebiTjbf7WcRodnk7P8721gqQ7Sn3KXgvogOmyQXw9GpaRFlQoHW9lWkgRkwAy2uncjKEALjD_2ZM23CB9nYP0rMU5pVFdjY6QKYQ2))/GUI/wbs.aspx`

and in Firefox it appears correctly `192.168.1.97:8080/GUI/wbs.aspx`

Does anyone know what could be the cause?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like IE11 is not accepting cookies for your production site, and also that you are allowing for cookieless sessions, so it is putting the session ID in the URL. This setting is in the `web.config` in the `authentication` setting. So you can force it to always use cookies like:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" ...
```

`cookieless` is set to one of [HttpCookieMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) values, of which there are four. The default is `UseDeviceProfile`, which is:

> If the setting indicates that the browser or device supports cookies,
>   cookies are used; otherwise, an identifier is used in the query
>   string.

So that is why you are seeing that strange URL. If you change it to `UseCookies`, then it will only use cookies and not IDs in the URL, and you will need to ensure you are accepting cookies, or else they won't stay authenticated.

[FormsAuthenticationConfiguration.Cookieless Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.cookieless%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)